# arduino yun sysupgrade 'platform_check_image' failed

Tags: arduino-yun

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSysupgrade
when i run the following command. i get this error.

```
run-sysupgrade /mnt/sda1/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-yun-16M-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
Image metadata not found
Invalid image type.
Image check 'platform_check_image' failed.
```

via webinterface its the same problem

i have a freshly unboxed arduino yun rev2

i really don't want to use the go updater since i still have 2 years of warranty.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/YunUpdater

Comment: Hint: The SD card should be inserted with Yun powered off, then once the card is in, power up the Yun.

Comment: @MikaelPatel didn't work. same problem.

Comment: Check that the SD is mounted `ls /mnt/sda1/`

Comment: @MikaelPatel it is. the bin shows up.

Comment: Check the size and contents of the file against the original. How did you download?